# simple gpu computation fails on MATLAB parallel processing toolbox

Tags: matlab, gpu

EDIT: the problem was due to my setup which shadowed the in-built assert function. Thanks to Edric for the tip (see comments below).

I am trying out the gpu capabilities of MATLAB with the example code but receving an error. I am not sure what the error means and how to fix it. The functions I am testing are built-in for gpu as described on [MATLAB's help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html). Here is as example, but similar error pops up for other functions.

```
>> x = gpuArray.ones(1,10)

x =

 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

>> y = cos(x);
>> gather(y)
Error using assert
Too many input arguments.

Error in parallel.internal.types.Atomic.validateIsScalar (line 133)

Error in parallel.internal.types.Atomic/cType (line 267)

Error in parallel.internal.ptx.ptxEmitter/mangleCprotoEntryLazyEval (line 2614)

Error in parallel.internal.gpu.ptxExpr (line 73)
```

Here is the gpuDevice output:

```
>> gpuDevice

ans = 

CUDADevice with properties:

                  Name: 'GeForce GTX 870M'
                 Index: 1
     ComputeCapability: '3.0'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 6.5000
        ToolkitVersion: 6
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
           MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
             SIMDWidth: 32
           TotalMemory: 6.4425e+09
   MultiprocessorCount: 7
          ClockRateKHz: 967000
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1
```

I will really appreciate any help/pointers.

Thanks

EDIT: I am using MATLAB 2014b

Comment: What does `which -all assert` return? Looks like you might have your own version shadowing the built-in version perhaps.

Comment: Edric, thats correct. There are assert functions in a library that I import which is shadowing the built-in assert function. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Hm, not really - short of either not using that library, or having it be compatible with MATLAB's `assert`.